# How to center a svg inside another svg with html div?

Tags: html, css, svg

As gif shows,
[image]

the clown svg is in minHand div which is supposed to be centered in the center of the background: another svg called back in clockBack div.

But when resizing the window, the clown looks like in the center of the body. Is there any way to center the clown(minHand) in the middle of the back(clockBack)? 
Any comments are welcome and appreciated.

code is in http://codepen.io/Debra/pen/NpPgxQ

clown.svg, https://app.box.com/s/x77ydnb9p293w7lyxuqw34p3l4uusv0w

back.svg, https://app.box.com/s/e3dkxqsewz09bc3pq1jqxksmyd53ud09

code structure is like,

```
<html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<div id="clockBack">

<div id="minHand">
</div><!--minHand-->



</div><!--clockBack-->

<style>

body{
  background-color:yellow;
}
#clockBack{
  background-image: url(back.svg), none;        
  z-index:-1;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  width:70%;
  height:70%;
}
#minHand{
    background-image: url(clown.svg), none;
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top:70%;
  left:50%;
}

</style>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add position: relative to #clockBack.
- Then Add top and left 50% to #minHand, and transform: translate(-50%, -50%) to perfectly center it vertically and horizontally.

See the result in [codepen.](https://codepen.io/prakashom2new/pen/oZgebO)

```
#clockBack{
  z-index:-1;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  width:70%;
  height:70%;
  position: relative;
}
#minHand {
  width:20%;
  height:20%;

  z-index:2;

  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```